# Width and Precision using *

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm learning Python from a book and came across this example:

```
>>> '%f, %.2f, %.*f % (1/3.0, 1/3.0, 4, 1/3.0)
# Result: '0.333333, 0.33, 0.3333'
```

Don't quite understand what's happening here, especially the '4' in between.

Comment: That is not valid python. You are missing a closing quote for the string and the "1.3.0" part probably should be "1/3.0" I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant something like this:

```
>>> '%f, %2.f, %.*f' % (1/3.0, 1.3, 4, 1/3.0)
'0.333333,  1, 0.3333'
```

`4` is a wild card value that is used in place of asterisk `*`. When expanded it would be equivalent to:

```
>>> '%f, %2.f, %.4f' % (1/3.0, 1.3, 1/3.0)
```

Comment: it might be more readable but you might not know what the field width will be

Comment: While more readable, it allows for less flexibility at runtime.

Comment: "..but you might not know what the field width will be" << care to elaborate? Thats what I'm not getting, whats the difference except the syntax? Thanks

Comment: @Nimbuz: difference is that `4` is determined at runtime and not hard-coded.

Comment: Aha! So like Bryan says, it can be a variable too that can take input from the user, correct?

Comment: Absolutely, that way the user can decide how many decimal places with which to be annoyed.

Answer (score 1):

There  are two syntax errors in the line you posted.  1.3.0 isn't a valid number, and the string isn't closed.

This is a valid version of said string format.

```
'%f, %2.f, %.*f' % (1/3.0, 1/3.0, 4, 1/3.0)
```

and outputs:

```
'0.333333, 0.33, 0.3333'
```

I couldn't find documentation on %.*f in [the official docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).  However, it appears that it's parsing the 4 to be how many decimal places you want to do the next argument at.

For example:

```
'%.*f' % (5, 1/3.0)
```

returns

```
'0.33333'
```

and

```
'%.*f' % (6, 1/3.0)
```

returns

```
'0.333333'
```

It seems to be a way to offer variable length precision, so you could allow your users to specify it.